# How to extract features from contour of hand?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, classification, opencv3.0, feature-extraction

I have done some preprocessing steps to obtain the contour. Now I have to extract features and prepare my training data. Since i am new to computer vision, I do not know the steps required to build a hand recognition system. All I have been able to do is to locate the contour of the hand. Can anyone guide me the rest of the steps, that is how to perform feature extraction, prepare the training data, perform classification and matching.

Comment: The question is too broad. Please narrow it down to a specific programming problem, showing what you've done so far to solve it.

Comment: I need to build a hand recognition system. Till now, I have only been able to capture video from camera, threshold the image to locate the hand and draw a contour across it. Now, I am stuck as I do not know how to proceed to perform feature extraction and prepare a training dataset. I am using opencv and c++.

Answer (score 0):

you should check this out...

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexitydefects

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-easiest-way-to-recognise-gestures-in-OpenCV-using-Python